# Training loop causing program to hang, crash, and exit with no error

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

I have been trying to train a lstm model with lyrics data I found on Kaggle. When I first started with this architecture, I had glove embeddings which worked fine with the model and how I shaped it. I switched tokenization and then z scoring my input parameters and all of a sudden my program hangs and then closes out without any error, I only found out about the error when I checked my Event viewer and found this:

```
Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 3.12.2150.1013, time stamp: 0x65c2a4c7
Faulting module name: c10.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x65a00f1b
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000060bb5
Faulting process id: 0x0x35EC
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1DA5E8859C9145E
Faulting application path: C:\Users\rohun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Users\rohun\final_train\env\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib\c10.dll
Report Id: 8d624ff4-59a7-448f-b320-6e7aeed0ecd4
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I’ve tried a lot of different things to fix like changing model architecture, data preprocessing, hardware limitations, gradient clipping, and such, but I haven’t found a single thing that could be causing me this problem.It seems that when I take out the loss.backwards() function the program runs like normal. I even tried running this in Google Colab to see if something might be wrong on my system but I got a similar problem where the program just crashed.

The problem seems to be originating from the preprocessing side because when I was using the glove embeddings it was working fine with the dataset.For reference here is the code for the training loop and preprocessing

**Preprocessing**

```
def preProcess(x):
    x = x.strip()
    x = x.lower()
    x = x.splitlines()

    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i].lower()
        x[i] = x[i].translate(table)
        x[i] = x[i].split()
        x[i].insert(0,"<BOS>")
        x[i].append("<EOS>")
        words_set.update(x[i])
    
    return x

print("Preprocessing staring...")
data = []
for index, row in df.items():
    data.extend(preProcess(row))


words_set = list(sorted(words_set))
for i,word in enumerate(words_set):
    number_to_words_dictionary[i] = word
    words_to_numbers_dictionary[word] = i



max_len = max(len(x) for x in data) - 1


#convert data into X and y data, with X being embeddings and y as numbers
X = []
Y = []

window_size = 3

print("token embeddings starting ...")
for i in range(len(data)):
    update = torch.tensor([])
    for j in range(len(data[i]) - window_size):
        keys = data[i][:j+window_size]
        X.append(torch.tensor(itemgetter(*keys)(words_to_numbers_dictionary)))
        Y.append(torch.tensor(words_to_numbers_dictionary[data[i][j+window_size]]))

print("token embeddings completed...")


print("padding sequences starting...")
padded_X = pad_sequence(X, batch_first=True).float()

mean = padded_X.mean(dim=None)
std = padded_X.std(dim=None)

# Z-score normalization
padded_X = (padded_X - mean) / std

print(padded_X.size())



Y = torch.tensor(Y).long()
```

**Training Loop**

```
 for epoch in range(epochs):
        if earlyStopping:
            break
        epoch_losses[epoch] = []
        print("Epoch: " + str(epoch))
        total_loss = 0
        running_loss = 0
        for i,batch in enumerate(training_data_loader):
            x_i, y_i = batch[0],batch[1]
            logits = model(x_i)
            loss = loss_fn(logits, y_i)
            optimizer.zero_grad()


            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
```